# ошибка в php 7.2 syntax error, unexpected 'int' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, syntax, parse

как решить эту ошибку?
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'int' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in C:\OSPanel\domains\pagination\Pagination.php on line 5

```
1 <?php 
2 
3 
4 class Pagination{
5   public int $count_pages = 1;
6   public int $current_page = 1;
7   public string $uri = '';
8   public int $mid_size = 5;
9   public int $all_pages = 10;
10 
11  public function __construct(
12      public int $page = 1,
13      public int $per_page = 1,
14      public int $total = 1,
15  )
16  {
17 
18  }
19 
20 }
```

Comment: Убрать `int` очевидно. Тайпхинтинг пропертей приехал только в php7.4. Так что `string` тоже надо убрать. И тем более объявление в конструкторе - они вообще с восьмой версии заезжают.

Comment: А как тогда это реализовать в php 7.2?
если я убираю int и все названия типов данных со строк 5-9. То дальше он начинает ругаться на 12 строку 'public'

Comment: Перечитай мой комментарий __еще раз__.

Comment: u_mulder ты тоже перечитай, я обновил свой вопрос

Comment: Объявление `public` \ `private` в конструкторе приехали в __восьмой версии__.

Comment: Получается мне просто удалить public и всё?

Comment: Вынести их выше из конструктора. Убрать public у __construct

Answer (score 1):

Для 7.2 правильно будет так

```
class Pagination{
    public $count_pages = 1;
    public $current_page = 1;
    public $uri = '';
    public $mid_size = 5;
    public $all_pages = 10;
    public $page;
    public $per_page;
    public $total;

    public function __construct(int $page = 1, int $per_page = 1, int $total = 1)
    {
        $this->page = $page;
        $this->per_page = $per_page;
        $this->total = $total;
    }
}
```